# Can a 3x3 Matrix in the Integers with Determinant 2 have this product with a 3x1 Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, integers

I've been doing some old Linear Algebra papers that my university library had on file just for some practise and came across this question which caused many a debate among my friends.

True or False:
There exists a Matrix A $\in \mathbb{M}_{33}(\mathbb{Z})$ with determinant 2 such that:

$$
   A
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 \\
   1 \\
   4
  \end{array} } \right]
 = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   4 \\
   -8 \\
   16
  \end{array} } \right]$$

I started by writing out each of the $[a]_{ij}$ entries and multiplying it out to look for a contradiction but that didn't get me very far. I then thought maybe since the determinant is 2 it may have something to do with the fact that $A^{-1}$ can be written as $\frac{1}{det(A)}B$ for some matrix B but a concrete answer still eludes me.
A pointer in the right direction would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule): if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $\det(A)\ne0$ then the solution of
$$A\pmatrix{x_1\cr\vdots\cr x_n\cr}={\bf b}$$
is given by
$$x_k=\frac{\det{A_k}}{\det A}\ ,$$
where $A_k$ is $A$ with the $k$th column replaced by $\bf b$.  If $A$ exists under the conditions of your problem we have
$$1=x_2=\frac{\det A_2}{\det A}\ .$$
But $A_2$ is an integer matrix in which every entry of the second column is a multiple of $4$, so $\det A_2$ is a multiple of $4$; and $\det A=2$; so $x_2$ is a multiple of $2$.  This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

define
$$
B =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then $\det B = 1,$ so $\det AB = 2.$ However, from the left hand column, we must have $\det AB$ divisible by $4.$

Contradiction

$$
AB =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
4 & ? & ? \\
-8 & ? & ? \\
16 & ? & ?
\end{array}
\right)
$$